# Asp.NET WebAPI custom authorization

Tags: asp.net, rest, authentication, authorization

I want to create a authorization mechanism for an application based on WebAPI and AngularJs.

I've seen some articles, which use BasicHttpAuthentication, but i really don't like the whole idea of sending username, and password on every request. The more it doesn't fit for me is because i want to use OpenId authentication, where you don't have username/password pair.

I'm thinking about a solution, but I don't really know how to implement it. The concept is that user is authenticated as in an usual Web application - posts a form with user / password or selects an OpenId provider. If the user is authenticated succesfully, it is placed in a static object, which stores the User object for a certain ammount of time. Next a usertoken is generated and passed to the Client Application. The client passes the token on each request to the server, if the user exists in the above mentioned static object with the appropriate authentication token it is authorized to get the data.

Firstly - Do you think this is a good approach to the problem?
Secondly - How should I pass the authentication token, WITHOUT using cookies? I guess it should sit in the request headers, like in BasicHttpAuthentication but, I really dont' know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

**BasicHttpAuthentication**

I'm with you on feeling dirty about caching the username and password on the client and forever transferring it with every request. Another aspect of Basic authentication that might work against you is the lack of sign-off. Other than changing the password, you can't "invalidate" a basic authentication session. Tokens on the other hand, will typically offer an expiration date, and if you want server-side invalidation you can check the issue date and say "any tokens older than issue date xyz are invalid".

**Server State**

You mention "If the user is authenticated successfully, it is placed in a static object". But this is independent of the token? This sounds like you're wanting to implement server state management of authentication sessions, but this isn't strictly necessary. The token itself should be sufficient for user authentication, managing server state is another potential obstacle. Server state can become difficult to manage when you factor app-pool recycles or web-farm environments (what if you want two services to share the same authentication token, but not require communication with a central "authentication server" for storing the state / session?)

**Passing Authentication Token**

Headers is definitely a good place for it. Really, where else is there? Cookies, Headers, Message. Other than a browser client, cookies don't make a lot of sense, and including it in the message can muddy your message formatting a bit, so headers is the only remaining option that makes much sense in my view.

**Client Implementation**

You've not specified, but I suspect you're interested in calling the service from .NET? In which case [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) could be your friend. In particular, the [DefaultRequestHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders.aspx) collection. You can use this to add a custom header to store your authentication token.

**Server Implementation**

When researching ASP.NET authentication recently, I learned a lot about customisation by examining the [Mixed Authentication Disposition ASP.NET Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx) (MADAM). I wasn't interested in using MADAM as-is, but learning about it from that article and examining the [source code](http://www.raboof.com/projects/madam/) gave me a lot of ideas of how I could insert my own authentication module into the web stack.

Comment: Based on your suggestion to use authentication token, how do we reset both the expiration date at each call made to the server? Who and how does the reset --- the client or the server?

Comment: By "reset the expiration date", I assume you're referring to a sliding expiration scenario? So the login call might return a token set for expiration in 2 hours, and each subsequent call (not necessarily to login) needs to reset that expiration to 2 hours from the time of call?  Both the client and server would need to be aware of the scenario. The server could send a new authentication token in the response headers for every call (with an updated expiration), the client then just reads that header and uses the new token for the next call.